# Does anyone know how to point a docker container to ngrok?

Tags: docker, nginx, ngrok

I have discourse which i installed through docker, however, i am trying to see if i can connect that through Ngrok.  Anyone familiar with Ngrok?

The app is running through a docker container at `localhost:9292`

when i try to run ngrok it does not work.

```
ngrok http -host-header=rewrite localhost:9292
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my questions in hopes that i can help some else.

So when i installed discourse through docker, i had to ssh into my docker container.  I then had to install nginx and config it to point my box IP address to my private network.  Once i reload it work, however, I was getting a blank page when i hooked it to ngrok.  SO....i had to turn off the security protocols in Chrome so that it allowed ngrok to display my app.  Let me know if anyone have any questions and id love to expand on this.

Answer (score 0):

this composer works for me

```
version: '3'
services: 
          
    yourwebserver:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ...
            target: ...
        container_name: yourwebserver
        volumes:
            - ...
        ports:
            - ...
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        depends_on: 
            - ngrok

            
    ngrok:
        image: ngrok/ngrok:alpine
        environment:
            NGROK_AUTHTOKEN: '...'
        command: 'http yourwebserver:80'        
        ports:
            - '4040:4040'
        expose:
            - '4040'
```